# Chart Wpf Tool Kit Handler drawing label

Tags: c#, wpf

I do not write English well.

I am using wpf-toolkit with linearserie trend.

I extract from the database via linq minutes a day
100
1200
... 
1300

and show them on the graph in the x-axis

I would like to convert this value into hours
hour: minutes = 1200 * 60 + ":" 1200% 60

show them the x-axis

the problem and the graph when there are a lot of data 
is hard to see so I should use

xAxis.Interval = sliderIntervalloX.Value;

it works fine for LineSeries (but is too slow to DateTimeSerie)

I would then intercept the writing on the x and write the value of the label

with the formula I wrote above

```
<charting:Chart Name="GraficoTemperatura"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Title="Grafico temperatura"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF4CAE78" Height="231.25" Width="576.25">

<chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>


<chartingToolkit:LinearAxis 
                    x:Name="xAxis"
                    Orientation="X" 
                    ShowGridLines="True"  
                    Location="Bottom" 
                    Title="Minuto della lettura"

                    >
</chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>  

 <charting:LineSeries                
DependentValuePath="Value" 
IndependentValuePath="Key"
ItemsSource="{Binding}" Title="Temperatura (°C)" AnimationSequence="FirstToLast" >

  <!-- style della linea -->
  <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
          <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      </Style>
  </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>

</charting:LineSeries>


</charting:Chart>
```

Comment: `I do not write English well` - XAML is the universal language thru which all WPF developers communicate and undertand each other. Post your current XAML.

Comment: I edited the post by entering the code
thanks

Comment: i resolve!!! paste the code

Answer (score 0):

solution

xaml resource

```
<local:RatingToStringConverter x:Key="RatingToStringConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="XAxisLabelStyle" TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AxisLabel">
                <!-- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label, Converter=}"/> -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RatingToStringConverter}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

xaml chart

```
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis  
                                        x:Name="xAxis"
                                        Orientation="X" 
                                        ShowGridLines="True"  
                                        Location="Bottom" 
                                        Title="Orario della lettura"  
                                        AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource XAxisLabelStyle}"
                                        >
```

on cs

```
public class RatingToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Validate parameters
            /*if (!(value is double))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported value type in RatingToStringConverter.");
            }
            */
            // Convert number to string
            //int  idoubleValue = Math.Ceiling ((double)value);
            int  doubleValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
            //int  doubleValue = (int)value;
            string a = (doubleValue / 60).ToString();
            string b = (doubleValue % 60).ToString();

            return a + ":" + b;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```